# Google workload identity federation integration with Azure DevOps

Tags: google-cloud-platform, azure-devops

I've already setup workload identity federation. We have created a management service account Where we are impersonating other Service Accounts.

We have 2 different release pipeline to deploy cloud function. We are using 2 different SA (service account) for each. Let's say SA1 and SA2.
When I deploy first release pipeline with SA1. It will deploy perfectly. When I run second pipeline just after previous pipeline. It will not deploying properly.

When I check the logs. It will start deploying with SA1 and getting permission issue. Its like SA not expiring completely and start deploying with previous one.
Task for second pipeline
[image]

**Release Pipeline logs**
Authenticated with external account credentials for: [app-deployer@project2-2629.iam.gserviceaccount.com].
2024-02-20T12:53:37.5811778Z Your current project is [project2-2629].  You can change this setting by running:
2024-02-20T12:53:37.5812138Z   $ gcloud config set project PROJECT_ID
2024-02-20T12:53:38.9624162Z AccessDeniedException: 403 app-deployer@project1-2620.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.objects.list access to the Google Cloud Storage bucket. Permission 'storage.objects.list' denied on resource (or it may not exist).

I've already tried to solve by force recreating token with '--force' and 'revoke --all' option but not working.

Comment: Have you created a new service connection using your SA2 and use it in your second release pipeline? To learn more about your pipeline, can you share the tasks you are using in your release pipeline and the corresponding configurations?

Comment: Hi @ZiyangLiu-MSFT, I've created a a service connection for SA2 as well. Sometime, Its working perfectly. But not every time. Looks like, second pipeline taking previous login session.
**Upload Artifact Script:**
`./google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud auth login --project=$(app2-project-name) --cred-file=$GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS  -q
./google-cloud-sdk/bin/gsutil cp $ARTIFACT_DIRECTORY/$ARTIFACT_SOURCE/app2/app2.zip gs://$(app2-project-bucket)/app2/app2.zip`

Comment: 1. Are you using a self-hosted agent or a MS-hosted agent? 2. How did you define the  variable  `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`? 3. Please check if you have provided the correct credential. According to the error message, the credential actually used is SA1. You can run the same commands on your local machine using the same secure file to deploy. If it has the same permission issue locally, the issue is related to your credential.